# Half-Half time boot failure of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS when installed alongside Windows 10 Enterprise

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, windows-10

I have a Dell PC preinstalled with Windows 10 Enterprise with only one disk C:/. I did the following to install Ubuntu.

1. To install Ubuntu, I first shrank C:/ to make two disks, C:/ and D:/, and then formatted D:/ to NTFS. I intend to use D:/ as a common disk space for both OS.
2. I made a bootable USB of Ubuntu 16.04 and then installed with default settings. After finishing installing, when I log in to Windows, I saw that C:/ becomes smaller and I couldn't not see Ubuntu disk. If I understand correct, Ubuntu is also installed into C:/ but formatted that part of C:/ into some format that Windows cannot read. Dual booting is set by Ubuntu by default.

[image: grub boot options]

3. Last I migrated all my user directories into D:/ for both Windows and Ubuntu. For Ubuntu, I followed the instructions on help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving. The result is that Windows and Ubuntu is sharing the same home folder, e.g. Documents in Windows and Ubuntu point to the same location.

I don't have any problem booting Windows. But booting Ubuntu is only successful about half of the time. There are three situations I have encountered:

1) Booting Ubuntu is successful.

2) After I select Ubuntu in grub, this screen appears.

[image: emergency mode]

If I type systemctl reboot, it doesn't work and this screen appears again. However, if I force power off the PC, and then boot Windows, restart and boot Ubuntu, it always works.

These two situations are equally likely, but situation 3) below is rather occasional.

3) After I select Ubuntu in grub, all words disappear. And the screen stays at purple color and stops responding. I tried to long press power button to force power off. If I turned on the PC again and boot Ubuntu, it worked.

I suspect it has something to do with keeping things intact in dual systems. A thing I should make clear is that I always close applications and turn off the PC correctly. No sudden lack of power or force power off after logged in has ever occurred.

Any ideas how I can solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this was caused by the default fast startup shutdown option of Windows 10. I followed the second approach on this link http://windowsten.info/tutorials/5767-how-to-fully-shut-down-windows-10, i.e. uncheck "Turn on fast startup (Recommended)" option at Control Panel/Hardware and Sound/Power Options/System Settings.

I've been using the two OS' for one week now, no startup problem ever occurred again.